# Simple laravel one-to-many relationship - get results from both tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

So I have a **Client** Model and a **Risk Category** Model. The relationships are shown below and the tables follow the normal conventions:

```
//Client.php
public function riskCategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('RiskCategory');
}

//RiskCategory.php
public function clients()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Client');
}
```

I want to query a client by id and also get the risk category data at the same time.

If I use `Client::find($id);` I get all the fields in the `clients` table for that ID and if I do `Client::find($id)->riskcategory;` I get just the fields for the risk category table.

Is there a way to get the fields from both tables at once? I.e. if I query for client with Id 175 I get all the client fields (name, age, address etc) and the risk category for that client in the same query?

Comment: Wow, a downvote within less than a second of posting, that's impressive reading speed

Comment: `$client = Client::find($id);` then you can do `$client->name` and `$client->riskcategory`

Comment: +1 to remove the unnecessary down vote.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the data from the risk category to the user in multiple ways. Depending on how you want to use it.

Use client data as array:

```
// get the client with ID 2 and eager load the riskcategory relation.
$client_data = Client::with('riskcategory')->find(2)->toArray();
```

Use client data as Eloquent:

```
// get the client with ID 2 and eager load the riskcategory relation.
$client = Client::with('riskcategory')->find(2);
```

More info about eager loading: [Eager loading info](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)

Comment: This works too but the `find()` method from @Razor is a bit cleaner than using a `where()->first()`.

Comment: the `toArray()` function doesn't work with an eloquent model. That's why I added it to the query model.

Changed the second method to find.

Comment: Just tried `toArray()` on your second example and it works for me. Both should just return an eloquent collection which you can then run `toArray()` on. Regardless, you answered my question so thanks.

Comment: @harryg O I thought it only worked on the Query model :). Changed it.

Answer (score 1):

simply use a variable

```
$client = Client::with('riskCategory')->find($id); // eager loading
echo $client->name;
echo $client->riskcategory;
```

Comment: This works thanks, but I'm confused as to why eager loading is needed as in normal SQL you could do this in one query with a `left join`

Comment: @harryg The eager part is adding the `left join` to the query when you run it (the find() start the query building).

Comment: if you don't use eager loading, each time you access to `$client->riskcategory;` a new query is called. So, if you are pretty sure that you use it only once, you can omit it.